# Match 4 digits exists in string

Tags: c#, regex

Ok, so this is one more of the multitude of regex questions, i have searched without finding the answer to this.

I want to know if the string contains a four digit number, but the number is not the whole string. It must also fail on 5 digit numbers.

So, this is what i have today: `\d{4}[^\d]`
And this works for most of my cases, but it breaks if the four digit number is in the end of the field.

Examples

```
#3333, INC343334    => I want 3333
dddd                => I want no match
3333                => I want 3333
RT4323, INC33334434 => I want 4323
INC23455667, #3333  => I want 3333
```

Comment: Could you provide some examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use negative lookahead and negative lookbehind to test that your 4-digit number is not surrounded by other numbers:

```
(?<!\d)\d{4}(?!\d)
```

This does not meet the requirement of filtering out strings which consist of *only* a four-digit number. I would recommend doing that filter seperately, like this psuedocode:

```
regex = /(?<!\d)\d{4}(?!\d)/;
strings.filter(s -> s.length != 4).filter(s -> regex.find(s).matches())
```

Comment: on regexstorm.com it did match the string "3333" also... 

I was guessing that i needed lookahead but i couldn't quite figure it out, thank you very much.

Comment: Ah, I think I misunderstood you when you said "I want to know if the string contains a four digit number, but the number is not the whole string", which to me implies that "3333" should not match. Anyway glad I could help :)